# Proof for solution of recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, catalan-numbers

I am studying the recurrence relation

$x(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x(i) x(n-i), \hspace{20px} x(1) = 1$

and have found without proof the explicit solution

$x(n) = \frac{(2n-2)!}{n!(n-1)!}, \hspace{20px} n \in \mathbb{N}$

Do you have a clever way to verify that this is indeed a solution? I can not find a way to erase the sum when inserting the expression in the relation.

Comment: Search Catalan number; it will give you the information you need.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!